# Semantic React / Background Image and height 100 vh

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Hello how could I make a Component Footer to occupy only 100 px of page height and the rest of the page to be a Component Grid

using height: vh
i try this with my content:

```
export const GridWrap = styled(Grid)`
&&& {
    background-image: url(${background});
    height: 90vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: fixed;
}
`
```

and this with my footer:

```
export const FooterWrap = styled.div`
&&& {
    background: #000;
    Height:10vh
}
```

but not sucess

code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/black-platform-hybgc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For footer with 100px of height:

```
height: 100px;
```

For content, the rest of the page:

```
height: calc(100vh - 100px)
```

Just replace current style in your code